# why does Mupad replaced my E(s) here?

Tags: mupad

I have the code:

```
  C(s):=E(s)*G(s);
  B(s):=C(s)*H(s);
  openLoopTransferFunction:=B(s)/E(s)
```

Why does Mupad gives as output e(s)?
Mupad output:

G(s)*exp(1)(s) (or written G(s)*e(s) in blue)

How can I keep my E(s) not changed automatically by Mupad ...To be honest this is retarded...
Bonus :(

....Wtf

E(s):=R(s)-B(s)
Error: The identifier 'E' is protected. [_assign]

Comment: Since I cannot answer my question anymore (banned) I will post here the solution:

U(s):=hold(E(s))+hold(E(s))

Ps: you can also use level(E(s),0) Pretty neat :) I love mupad :))

Answer (score 0):

There are some protected identifiers in MuPAD. Usually, they use uppercase letters. For example, `I` denotes the imaginary unit, and `E` represents Euler's number. See the difference between entering `E` (upright letter 'e') and `e` (slanted letter 'e').

If you want to use any of these identifiers in your fashion, you can `unprotect` them:

```
unprotect E
```

results in:

```
ProtectLevelError
```

which is not an error message but the former protection level that you just changed. Check the succesful change by entering the same command again. This time, you will get:

```
ProtectLevelNone
```

Now you can assign to `E` as you would to any other identifier:

```
E(s) := R(s) - B(s);
```

will give the expected result.

If you want to not define `E` explicitly, you should delete it after lifting the protection:

```
delete(E)
```

Then it will be available like any other symbol.

In any case, if you need to use the Euler's number later, you will have to use `exp(1)` instead of `E`.

To get a list of all length-one identifiers, type:

```
select(op(map(op(anames(All)), expr2text)), x -> bool(length(x) = 1))
```

giving:

```
"E", "I", "O", "D"
```

Similarly, for length two, this gives:

```
"N_", "Re", "R_", "Si", "C_", "is", "Z_", "op", "id", "Li", "ln", "Im", "Ax",
"Q_", "fp", "Ci", "Ei"
```